# Oracle debug session exits instantly for trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to debug a compound trigger. I compiled it for debug,and put breakpoints on the trigger and hit "debug". Then it prompts me a window for a PL/SQL block. I entered my sql statement, and hit "OK".

The debug session just ends instantly

I got following message in the Debugging Message window:

```
Connecting to the database EFTS.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '6503' )
Debugger accepted connection from database on port 6503.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database EFTS.
Debugger disconnected from database.
```

Strangely, the debugger works for stored procedures. I am able to trace through the procedures line by line. However, for TRIGGER, it just ended instantly.

Trigger Declaration:

```
create or replace TRIGGER 
MySchema.T_EVNTS_UPSERT
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON MySchema.MyTable
COMPOUND TRIGGER
```

SQLDeveloper Version: the latest

Oracle Version: 12c

Comment: and what was your sql statement?  Was it doing the DML expected by the trigger declaration?

Comment: It was a simple insert, I will update my trigger declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have changed this setting

[image]

It should say instead 'Step Into'

Also ensure the lines of pl/sql with breakpoints are executable lines of code, otherwise they'll be ignored.

Comment: I had it set to Run Until A Breakpoint Occurs.  
Changing to either "Step Over" or "Step Into" Fixed the problem. Not sure why the first option doesn't work.

Comment: no breakpoints could be found is my best guess

Comment: which is also strange because the breakpoint I set on a line will always run. It was a simple +1 on one of the integer.

Comment: the other thing that can cause that to be ignored is if the trigger wasn't compiled for DEBUG...but could be a bug with the debugger?